# assign path variable dependend on user

Tags: sas

I want to assign a path variable called `folder`depending on the user. I am using the following code. But I always have to run this code twice to work properly. Any ideas why? Do I need to initialize the `userid`variable in any way?

```
%global folder;
data _null_;
  userid = &sysuserid.;
  if userid in ('user1', 'user2') then do;
    call symput('folder','<special_path>');
  end;
  else do;
    call symput('folder',"<default_path>");
  end;
  %put NOTE: user is &sysuserid. path to '<standard folder>' folder assigned is &folder.;
run;
```

Comment: I think &userid is reserved variable? At least in my system it comes from windows first.lastname, which is interpretated as having macro dot. Try **userid= "&userID"**; Also adjsut latter **in** statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the order of events happening:-

1. Macro variables are resolved and imputed in your data-step code.
2. The data-step code with imputed(resolved) macro values gets submitted.

So when you submit your code, what actually gets submitted is this:-

```
data _null_;
  userid = SOME_USER_ID;
  if userid in ('user1', 'user2') then do;
    call symput('folder','<special_path>');
  end;
  else do;
    call symput('folder',"<default_path>");
  end;
  %put NOTE: user is &sysuserid. path to '<standard folder>' folder assigned is ;
run;
```

That is why the put statement does not resolves the macro variable folder in the first instance.

Solution is -> bring the `%put` statement outside datastep.